# Get min value based on foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck on how to get a student's minimum score from `marks` table and `student` info from student table.

**EDIT: sorry for not mentioning, but i need result for user 1, st1**

student

```
id name
1  st1
2  st2
```

marks

```
student_id course_name marks
1          C++         55
1          OOP         65
1          AI          45  //need this lowest result for st1
2          C++         82
2          STATS       74
2          OS          20 // lowest marks are these for st2 or overall
```

**Edit forgot to enter name st1:**

Desired Output:

```
id name course_name MinMarks
1  st1  AI          45
```

I tried this query but it gives wrong `course_name` (C++) 1st row's course name

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, m.course_name, MIN(m.marks) FROM student s
JOIN marks m
ON s.id = m.student_id
Where s.id = 1
```

Output:

```
id name course_name MinMarks
1  st1  C++         45
```

Comment: Is ur query executing properly? I don’t think so. In ur query u have “user_id” but it should be “student_id’.marks table don’t has any “user_id” column.

Comment: sorry i have a test DB with user table, but i am working on student table. I'll correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select *
from marks 
where marks = (select min(marks) from marks)
```

or `left join`:

```
select m.*
from marks m
left join (select min(marks) as marks from marks) m_min on m.marks = m_min.marks
where m_min.marks is not null
```

It guarantees you that if there is more then one student with the minimum `mark` it displays all of them.

`left join` can possibly improve performance, you can check your execution plan to be sure.

*P.S.: If you also need to retrieve `name` from `student` table (is not stated in your desired output) you can do the `join` operation you did in your query:*

using subquery:

```
select m.student_id
     , s.name
     , m.course_name
     , m.marks 
from student s
join marks m on s.id = m.student_id
where m.marks = (select min(marks) from marks)
```

using `left join`:

```
select m.student_id
     , s.name
     , m.course_name
     , m.marks 
from student s
join marks m on s.id = m.student_id
left join (select min(marks) as marks from marks) m_min on m.marks = m_min.marks
where m_min.marks is not null
```

**Edit**

As it turns out, *OP* needs a minimum `marks` per `student`'s `id` (for the `id = 1`), so :

```
select m.student_id
     , s.name
     , m.course_name
     , m.marks 
from student s
join marks m on s.id = m.student_id
left join (select student_id, min(marks) as marks from marks group by student_id) p on s.id = p.student_id and p.marks = m.marks
where s.id = 1 and p.student_id is not null
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best approach since the select statement - `(select min(marks) from marks)` - will be run for each row in the marks table. Performance wise this is not a great option. @Abhik has used a better approach with the join.

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes: Yep, considering that it is MySQL, it can be a problem. The only thought I have is to rewrite a query with a `left join`.

Comment: @notulysses sorry for not mention before, but i need result for user 1 st1. can u plz have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: +1 i used ur 1st answer with extra where caluse in sub query and it workd. select *
from marks 
where marks = (select min(marks) from marks WHERE student_id = 1). Thanks a lot

Comment: @notulysses ur edit is returning all record but lowest marks row.

Comment: @Bsienn : typo – `is not null`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```sql
Select s.id, s.name, m.course_name, m.marks From student s 
right join marks m 
on s.id = m.user_id where m.marks = MIN(m.marks);
```

Comment: you can't use aggregate/group functions in `where` clauses. i dont even know how these answers get voted up

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
select
  s.id,
  s.name,
  m.course_name,
  m.marks
from
  student s 

  inner join marks m on
    m.student_id = is.id

  inner join (
    select
      student_id,
      min(marks) min_mark
    from
      marks m
    group by
      student_id
  ) min_marks on
    min_marks.student_id = s.id and
    min_marks.student_id = m.student_id and
    min_marks.min_mark = m.marks
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for only *one* student with the minimum mark, I would suggest `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, m.course_name, m.marks
FROM student s JOIN
     marks m
     ON s.id = m.user_id
ORDER BY m.marks ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

This solution will not work if you are looking for *all* students that have the same minimum mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, m.course_name, m.marks
FROM marks m
JOIN student s
ON m.student_id = s.id
WHERE m.student_id=1 AND m.marks = (SELECT MIN(marks) FROM marks WHERE student_id=1)
```